# Passing JSON data from JavaScript using Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, post

I have the following JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
'use strict';
var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) {
        if ( (ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 300) || (ajax.status == 304) ) {
            var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            var file = '';
            file += 'Original: ' + data['org'].file + '<br>';
            file += 'Processed: ' + data['pre'].file + '<br>';
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = file; 
        } else {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + ajax.statusText;
        }
    }
};

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    ajax.open('POST', 'resources/test.json', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    ajax.send(null);
};
};
```

I would like to pass the data from

> data['org'].file

and

> data['pre'].file

to PHP and have it echo out the value using the POST method.  Please no jQuery solutions this needs to be strictly JavaScript.

Something like this:

```
<?php $data = $_POST['the_data']; echo $data; ?>
```

Here is the JSON from test.json:

```
{
"org": {
    "file": "css/original.css"
},
"pre": {
    "file": "css/preprocessed.css"
}
}
```

Comment: I'm very confused about what `data['org'].file` and `data['pre'].file` are. What does your markup look like?

Comment: data['org'].file and data['pre'].file is the JSON, I'll post the JSON code now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a PHP script to echo JSON data, it's as simple as this:

```
<?
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    //...
    echo $json;
?>
```

To post it from Javascript, I reccomend reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). There's a reason so many people use jQuery...

Comment: I've tried that method but had no success.  Not sure the data is available and hence nothing is echoed. I'm looking into the link you sent but it seems to be consistent around information gathered from a form and not JSON. If the information is available through the DOM I would not be in this pickle. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I've been using that exact code for over 8 months (and several million JSON requests) without issue. What exactly goes wrong? That code should take any JSON data POSTed to the page and return it exactly.

Comment: My impression is that the JSON data isn't loaded initially so there is nothing to echo.  The user interacts with a button but by the time the data is parsed I believe the echo statement has already run. The variable $json is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on [JSON Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) you can use that to encode your data.

Then after you encoded you can send it wherever you need.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. There are a LOT of characters valid in JSON that aren't valid in certain places, such as HTTP cookies or URL addresses. If you use JSON.stringify(), you more likely than not need to encode it specially as well.

Comment: I've tried using stringify but passing the data to PHP has proven to be more a difficult process.  Once I use stringify what's my next move?

Comment: after you encode it you basically have some "`text`" that you can send using ajax http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

when you get it on the server side you can decoded with json_decode()

Comment: I'll have a look at the article and get back to you.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome don't forget to choose it as a good answer if it helped